# Python's replace() function's count property is vague

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I am relatively new to Python and don't really grasp the idea of `replace` method's third parameter (count).

So this:

```
print("This is is it!".replace("is", "are", __count=1))
print("This is is it!".replace("is", "are", __count=2))
```

produces:

```
Thare is is it!
Thare are is it!
```

How does count work in this case? Because according to my research and understanding, count is [An integer specifying number of replacements to perform](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-string-replace-method/). So, in this case, shouldn't the output be:

```
Thare are is it!
Thare are are it!
```

Any help for my understanding would be appreciated!

PS: I am using`Python version: 3.11.4`. As per this version, `count=1` is invalid!

Yet another PS: I did **not** see the `is` in `This` for some reason. So replace makes sense now. It replaces the `is` in `This` that's why it does not replace the second `is` in the first example. I just overlooked that detail :/

Comment: Why do you write `__count` and not `count`?

Comment: `count=1` means you perform 1 replacement, namely `This` to `Thare`. Why do you expect it to replace the second `is` ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce - `TypeError: str.replace() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: `print("This is is it!".replace("is", "are", 1))
print("This is is it!".replace("is", "are", 2))` runs for me. OP's code gives an error

Comment: Your replacements worked perfectly. Every instance of 'is' was replaced the number of times you requested.

Comment: It seems like you're not counting the replacement inside `This`, even though you actually make that replacement in your expected results.

Comment: Maybe you should using regular expressions to check for word boundaries; that way, you won't have to worry about replacing text in the middle of words: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html So for example, the sentence  `"This is a test, it is."` would become `"This are a test, it are."` and not `"Thare are a test, it are."`

Comment: I am using Python version `3.11.4` maybe that's the reason you are getting an Error? Because when I write `count=1` I do get error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `count` parameter in `replace()` specifies the maximum number of occurrences of the old substring (the first argument) to replace with the new substring (the second argument). It does not mean to replace all occurrences by default.

When you specify `count=1` only one occurrence of "is" will be replaced:

"Th**is** is is it!" turns into "Th**are** is is it!"

Comment: They seem to understand this, since they didn't replace the second word "is" in their first example. They're just not counting correctly for some reason.

Comment: Hence the highlighted part in my answer, to show that there is indeed 1 replacement.

Comment: As per your highlight, your solution is correct! I did not see that